# python use variable in regex as repetition amount

Tags: python, regex

Say for example I want to match a substring if it contains a certain number of some character. However, I don't know the exact amount that character is, but I know it is not negative. How would I write this regex?

```
from sys import stdin
import re
k = int(raw_input())
combo = re.compile(r'(?=(.*1.*){k})')
print [ s for s in combo.findall(stdin.readline().strip()) ]
```

Is this possible to do? If so, how do I do it?

EDIT:
Example input:
k = 2
string = 01010

Expected output: "101", "0101", "1010", "01010"

So in each substring, it contains exactly 2 characters '1'

Comment: Could you perhaps give an expected input/output?

Comment: what does it mean `k` here?

Comment: k is number of times to match the character being sought after in each substring. I put an example input/output above

Comment: What output would you want for `11110000`?

Comment: Say if k = 2, output should be:
11, 11, 11, 110, 1100, 11000, 110000

Comment: So if a substring matches twice (like `11`), then it should only be found once? But otherwise all overlapping substrings should be found? This looks like a problem with high computational complexity - how large are the strings going to be in real life that you're dealing with?

Comment: Strings are in the range of 1-10^6 characters long

EDIT: There was a mistake in my output above, look at the corrected output

Comment: @Smac89: Do you know how many overlapping substrings a one-million-character string has?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31509/discussion-between-smac89-and-tim-pietzcker)

Comment: It seems to be an average alorithmical problem. Like a hometask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after these many years, someone upvoted this question.

At first, I couldn't recall where I first saw this problem when I posted the question on SO. **No it wasn't homework as implied by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019235/python-use-variable-in-regex-as-repetition-amount#comment24596761_17019235) comment**, but just typing a few keywords into Google, I found the problem description in the following places:

- https://leetcode.com/problems/count-binary-substrings/
- https://www.codechef.com/problems/STRSUB
- https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/165/C (I believe this is the specific one I was working on)

And I was right about codeforces. I see that I had actually come up with a solution and submitted it. Here was my fastest solution: https://codeforces.com/contest/165/submission/4171748:

```py
k = int(raw_input())
 
def stable_search( zero, bin_num ):
    import collections
    c_one = ans = temp_ans = temp_z = 0
    c_zero = collections.deque()
    for f in bin_num[zero:]:
        if f == '1':
            c_zero.append(zero); zero = 0
            c_one = -~c_one
            if c_one >= k:
                ans = ans + ( temp_z * temp_ans ) + temp_z
                temp_ans = 0; temp_z = -~c_zero.popleft()
        else: temp_ans, zero = -~temp_ans, -~zero
    return ans + ( temp_z * temp_ans ) + temp_z
 
def mid(bin_num):
    return stable_search(bin_num.find('1'), bin_num)
 
def find_zeros(bin_num):
    import re
    return sum((len(sed)*-~len(sed))>>1 for sed in re.findall( '0+', bin_num))
 
if k == 0: print find_zeros(raw_input())
else: print mid(raw_input())
```

Yikes! Look at all that bit-twiddling (I must have recently learnt about bitwise operations). Btw, `-~n` just adds one to `n` .

Looking at the code again, I see that regex is used to solve one aspect of the problem (when `k` is 0), but otherwise the rest is done using a technique I not sure I fully understand now. This looks like a 2 pointer problem, but I think there may be more to it especially given the time limit.

As you can see, the solution runs in `O(N)` time and was written in python 2 (*there was a rumor back then that python 3 was slower than python 2, so everyone religiously stuck with python 2, including yours truly*). Let's see if rewriting it in python 3 really makes it slower:

https://codeforces.com/contest/165/submission/115388714

Nope! It got faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import collections
import re

def find_bin_ksubs (k: int, bin_num: str) -> int:
    tmp_z = tmp_count = count = count_1 = 0
    zeros = collections.deque()
    count_0 = bin_num.find('1')
    if count_0 == -1:
        return 0

    for b in bin_num[count_0:]:
        if b == '1':
            zeros.append(count_0)
            count_0 = 0
            count_1 += 1
            if count_1 >= k:
                count = count + (tmp_z * tmp_count) + tmp_z
                tmp_count = 0
                tmp_z = zeros.popleft() + 1
        else:
            count_0 += 1
            tmp_count += 1

    return count + (tmp_z * tmp_count) + tmp_z


def find_empties (bin_num: str) -> int:
    reg = re.compile(r'0+')
    return sum((count ** 2 + count) >> 1 \
        for zeros in reg.findall(bin_num) if (count := len(zeros)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (k := int (input ())) == 0:
        print (find_empties(input()))
    else:
        print (find_bin_ksubs(k, input()))
```

### EDIT

To be fair, computers have evolved since 2013, so I decided to upload the python2 solution one more time just to make the comparison fair...well it looks like the rumors are still true:

https://codeforces.com/contest/165/submission/115434939

Answer (score 7):

regexes are strings, so feel free to use your favorite string formatting construct:

```
combo = re.compile(r'(?=(.*1.*){%d})' % k)
```

As to your edited question, I can't find an easy way to do that with regexps, how about the following?

```
def all_substrings(s):
    m = len(s)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(i, m):
            yield s[i:j+1]

s = '01010'
print [x for x in all_substrings(s) if x.count('1') == 2]
```

Comment: Ok this works, but it does not produce the correct output, any help?

Comment: @Smac89: Your approach is fundamentally wrong. `.*` matches any string, so `.*1.*` matches `11111` - you can't count or enumerate substrings that match a given number of `1`s that way.

Comment: If it is an obvious solution, can you say or please tell me a way to get it to match the correct substrings

Comment: Whoa. @Smac89 just wrote that his strings may be 10^6 characters long. Bye-bye to a solution that finishes before the heat death of the universe...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: yeah, people always forget these minor details ;)